# set module name in ACL

Tags: acl, phalcon

Is it possible to define module name in 'Resourse'?

Such as what I illustrated here:

```
// Define the "Customers" resource in "Backend" module
$customersResource = new \Phalcon\Acl\Resource("Backend\Customers");

// Add "customers" resource with a couple of operations
$acl->addResource($customersResource, "search");
$acl->addResource($customersResource, array("create", "update"));
```

Comment: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/582

Comment: @Phantom I saw it before this and haven't any right solution